# No assets found when searching in different locale

Tags: assets, localization, search

At the moment I'm working on my first Craft CMS project. There I have two different locales that share the same assets folder.

The assets can be seen and used between the different locales but when I try to search I only get results in one locale. This is strange because they show up in the full list when selecting that locale.

Any tips? Did I miss a certain setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug on Craft 2 that has been resolved in the upcoming Craft 3 release.  Here's the original Github issue: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/17

Comment: Hi Brad, is there any way this fix can be backported to Craft 2?

Comment: Unlikely... the fix was part of a much larger refactoring.